# Yii2 project size more than 400mb

Tags: php, web, yii, yii2, composer-php

I am working on the yii2 framework. I had installed two extensions using the composer.

1. https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput.
2. https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone

After some days I realised that the size of my project is more than 400mb! It is normal and ok? Will the performance of my application decrease because of this?

I used require to install the extensions.

```
composer require "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput:@dev"
```

I feel the size is increasing because of these extensions.

composer.json

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
"description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
    "yiister/yii2-gentelella": "~1.0",
    "perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone": "dev-master",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "@dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
    "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800,
    "fxp-asset":{
        "installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
        "setPermission": [
            {
                "runtime": "0777",
                "web/assets": "0777",
                "yii": "0755"
            }
        ],
        "generateCookieValidationKey": [
            "config/web.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you share your composer.json file ?

Comment: Well, did you uploaded and saved files by this extensions?

Comment: @Yupik no i didnt.

Comment: How much space is exacly taken by `/vendor` directory?

Comment: @Yupik its taking exactly 429.9Mb

Comment: @AnarBayramov I edited the question and added the composer.json

Comment: @Yupik vender directory takes 260mb.

Comment: So it's okay, rest of your project takes space.

Comment: 260mb comes from dependencies one of them is an admin panel. which probably requires various of js and bootstrap libraries.

Comment: check for you runtime and web/asstes directory  .. the most of the space is used for the runtime activities ..

Comment: @scaisEdge my runtime and web/asset is 7.4 mb

Comment: @AnarBayramov is it fine if the project is that big?

Comment: your project is 140 mb. your dependencies are big if you use them all then its normal

Answer (score 0):

Please if you use yii2 framework check this files path and delete there content:

project_path/frontend/web/assets/

project_path/backend/web/assets/ 
and delete there content they are the cashed version of views
maybe this will help you reduce the size of project before uploading the file to server if that what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
{project}/backend/runtime
{project}/backend/web/assets
{project}/frontend/runtime
{project}/backend/web/assets
```

you can remove temp files from about folders

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you uploaded more big files in uploads, check if uploads directory dont contain big uploaded files, you can set the limits  on fileinput up to 5mb.